# Capture Recaptcha fail event on Contact Form 7

Tags: plugins, plugin-contact-form-7

In the contact form 7 plugin, there is a field to highlight if the message hasn't been sent.

```
Sender's message failed to send
```

If the recaptcha fails, this message associated with this field appears.

Is it possible to distinguish a recaptcha fail from all the other possible failures?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask via Contact Form 7 support area. This place is not for

CT7 has a bunch of hooks/filters built in to their code. You'll have to dig into their code to find them all. The docs that you can find about CF7 filter/hooks is third-party, and not well-maintained (many years old).

Asking CF7 for current filter/hook documentation will get you 'crickets', though...